# Can Mapping be public inside a struct?

Tags: solidity

[image]

```
struct Balance{
      uint totalBalance;
      uint numPayment;
      mapping(uint=>Payment) public payments;
    }
```

Can I make the mapping public inside the struct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code,
`mapping(uint=>Payment) public payments;`

uint is the data type and Payment is not. Payment may be struct. the mapping works on storing one data type into another. like mapping(uint => address) or mapping(address => uint).

Answer (score 2):

yes, but you need to remove public keyword, assuming Payment is a valid data type as Mazharul mentioned

although I don't follow the design, something like this doesn't throw compile errors

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract test {

struct Payment{
    uint amount;
    uint timeStamp;
}

struct Balance{
      uint totalBalance;
      uint numPayment;
      mapping(uint => Payment) payments;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A struct is an abstract data structure, struct member don't have any visibility.

Only variables that are defined using the struct type can have visibility modifiers.

Therefore, you should delete the `public` keyword from your mapping. You would only want to specify the visibility if you were to declare a mapping of `Balance` types, e.g. if you want to make it `internal`:

```
mapping(address => Balance) internal balances;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` defines a new Type consisting of members. Think "string", "bool", etc. Type is not an instance, so there's nothing to inspect.

You would have to make an instance with something like `Balance public b`, and `b` would be viewable via a "free" getter that is roughly:

```
function b() public view returns(Balance memory) {
  return b;
}
```

But there's a problem. The "free" getter is compiler sugar and it is not smart enough to handle a nested `mapping` like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract StructMapping {

    struct Foo {
        mapping(uint => uint) bars;
    }

    mapping(address => Foo) public fooBars;
}
```

But you can work it out yourself. Since the mapping leads to a struct that contains a mapping there are two indexes in play (the part the compiler sugar doesn't handle). You can make a function to tell it what to do:

```
contract StructMapping2 {

    struct Foo {
        mapping(uint => uint) bars;
    }

    mapping(address => Foo) private fooBars;

    function getFooBar(address foo, uint bar) public view returns (uint) {
        return fooBars[foo].bars[bar];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.